# Filter data based on matches within data

Tags: sql, sed, filter, awk

A comma separated file contains two columns with two strings.

```
A, abc*
A, abc.def.ghi
A, abc.def.ghi.jkhl
B, abc.def.gh
B, cde.def.abc
B, cde.def.*
```

The char * is a wildcard matching zero or more.

What is the simplest way to remove reduntant lines, i.e matches to any wildcard line?
Preferably with Unix filters or SQL, but any non-gui solution is helpful.

Expected output:

```
A, abc*
B, abc.def.gh
B, cde.def.*
```

Comment: If you are working with a file, why do you have this tagged "sql"?

Comment: Can the file contain any regex characters other than the dot and the star (that is: `.` and `*`)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the file could be imported and queried with SQL. I didn't want to restrict it to command line tools.

Comment: @HåkonHægland * is the only char in the string (abc.def.ghi*) that should be treated as a regex char.

Comment: Is there only one star on a line, and if so: is it the last character on the line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk -F \* 'NR==FNR{if (/\*/)a[$1]}
NR>FNR{  if (/\*/)
       {print;next}
   s=0
   for (i in a)
       {if ($0~i){s++;break}}
   if (s==0) print
}' file file
```

#### Explanation

- `-F \*` Use * as Field-Splitting
- `if (/\*/)a[$1]` save $1 of the line with * into array a, so get two : `A, abc` and `B, cde.def.`
- The next part in `NR>FNR`, read the file again, if the line has *, print directly. If not, calculate if the current line match `A, abc` or `B, cde.def.`. If finally s is still is 0, that means no match, print, otherwise, skip.

Comment: Nice.. But assuming the star is the last character on the line, and there is no regex characters in `i`..

Comment: I did not vote you down.. I usually do not vote down any answers.. It was just a comment.. and I think you have many good answers here (on SE)..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in SQL as:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t.col1 = t2.col1 and
                        t.col2 like replace(t2.col2, '*', '%') and
                        t.col2 <> t2.col2
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort YourFile | sed '#n
H
$ {s/.*//;H;x
: again
   s/\(\n\)\([^*[:cntrl:]]\{1,\}\)[*][^[:cntrl:]]*\(.*\)\n\2[^[:cntrl:]]*\n/\1\2*\3\1/
   t again
   s/^\n\(.*\)\n[[:blank:]]*$/\1/
   p
   }'
```

`sort` is used because it faster than make it in sed and to simplify the order to test content (string with * are always before other starting the same pattern).

Principe:
find any pattern starting after a `\n` and ending with * somewhere after, if it is the case, substitute the found line to nothing and retry (`t again`). [:cntrl:] is used to catch the \n that cannot be insedted in posix sed.

To use with GNU sed add `--posix` option (maybe 1 `-`)